# Expected earnings from a lottery ticket

Tags: probability

> A lottery type game consists of matching the correct three numbers
> that are selected from the numbers 1 through 12. The cost of one
> ticket is $1. If your ticket matched the three selected numbers, you
> win \$100. What are your expected earnings?

### Attempt

Let $X$ be number of matches with the winning numbers. We see that

$$ P(X=3) = \frac{3}{12} = \frac{1}{4} $$

Thus,

$$ P(X \neq 3) = \frac{3}{4} $$

now, let $Y= \text{winnings}$, we have $Y= -1$ if $X\neq 3$ and $y=100-1=99 $ if $X =3$. Thus,

$$ \mathrm{E}[Y] = -1 \cdot \frac{3}{4} + 99 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{96}{4}  $$

But, this answer is wrong as the correct answer is supposed to be $-0.54$. What am I missing here?

Comment: The *expected number* of matches is $1/4$.  That's a far cry from saying that the probability of getting three matches is $1/4$.  How many ways are there to choose $3$ numbers from among $12?$  Only one of these wins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't see that $\mathsf P(X=3)=1/4$ because it is not so.

That $1/4$ is the probability for the *first* draw being from the three matchables among the twelve possibles.   Which is not the event of interest.

You want the probability for selecting three from three numbers when selecting three from twelve (without bias or replacement).   Ie that *all three* draws match.

> $$\mathsf P(X=3)=\dfrac{\dbinom 33}{\dbinom {12}3}=\cfrac{{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}}{{12\cdot 11\cdot 10}}=\dfrac{1}{220}$$

Comment: just a quick question, the reason of ${3 \choose 3}$ is it because there is only one way to get the three correct numbers?

Comment: @JimmySabater Yes.  "The only way to win is to match *the* three correct numbers"

Answer (score 1):

There where two possible answers to consider in this. The first is where order of the numbers matters (*permutations*) or where it doesn't (*combinations*):

#### Order Matters

If order matters, than there are $1728$ possible combinations $\left(\frac{1}{12}^3\right)$. In which case the expected value won is: $$\left(\frac{1}{12}^3\cdot \left(100-1\right)\right)-\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{12}^3\right)\cdot1\right) \approx -0.94$$

#### Order Doesn't Matter

In the instance that order does not matter, there are $12 \choose3$ possibilities. Which comes out to $220$. Then our formula looks like so:  $$\left(\frac{1}{220}\cdot \left(100-1\right)\right)-\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{220}\right)\cdot1\right) \approx -0.545$$

Which is the correct answer. Hope that helps.